# DotNetNuke parse HTML before display

Tags: dotnetnuke

Could anyone tell me if there's some way of "hooking in" to DotNetNuke so that I can, for example, search and replace text for ALL HTML modules on the site?

e.g. if I use an HTML editor and enter the text {{replace_me}}, then I could have some code that detects "{{replace_me}}" every time a page is rendered and replace it with something else.

Please note that this is a simple example - there may be other ways of "replacing" text - however the actual use case we have is very specific and there will be some significant processing to decide what to replace :) - so whatever solution we implement should basically be:

Get HTML from DB -> Process it however we wish in full C# -> Deliver the modified string.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this with the use of an HTTPModule. Ifinity.com.au used to sell a module that did this, looks like you might be able to download it now for free (maybe?) at http://www.ifinity.com.au/Products/Inline_Link_Master/Product_Details